# Create component in template from data variable

Tags: vue.js

I have multiple components that take same props. I want to use those components in template in such a way that I don't use multiple if-else statements in my template. I created an object in my data and paired my components with string keys. Is there a way to call those components in template with that object ? My data object looks something like this:

```
componentMap:{
  "testComponent1":TestComponent1,
  "testComponent2":TestComponent2,
},
```

For example, if I give "testComponent1" as key, then in template it should use TestComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `component` tag.

```
<component :is="componentMap['testComponent1']"></component>
```

See the [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)